# Solutions with x,y positives integer for ${x}^{4}+4\,{x}^{3}+6\,{x}^{2}+4\,x+16={y}^{2}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, modular-arithmetic

I search all solutions (x,y) where x and y are both positive integer for the equation ${x}^{4}+4\,{x}^{3}+6\,{x}^{2}+4\,x+16={y}^{2}$

First i work mod (2) i have ${x}^{4}≡{y}^{2}$ (mod 2) and then $x≡y$ ( mod 2)

So x and y are both even or both odd.

We can find easily for x = 0 we have y = 4 and (0 ; 4) is a solution but how many solutions there are ?

Please explain me, thanks.

Comment: Hint: We have $(x+1)^2<y=\sqrt{(x+1)^2+15}$. The right hand side is less than $(x+1)^2+1$ for large enough $x$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rewrite as
$$(x^2+2x+1)^2+15=y^2\implies y^2-A^2=15$$

for $A=x^2+2x+1\in \mathbb Z$

But then $(y-A)(y+A)=15$ so we seek divisors of $15$, and there are only a few cases to check.